# .ToListAsync() not found when using WhereIf

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am reading [this tutorial](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Articles/Introduction-With-AspNet-Core-And-Entity-Framework-Core-Part-1/index.html#ArticleCreateFirstMigration). I want to use `async` query with EF Core.

It works well when i use like this:

```
var tasks = await _taskRepository
    .GetAll()
    //.WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input?.Title), x => x.Title.Contains(input.Title))
    //.WhereIf(input?.State != null, x => x.State == input.State.Value)
    //.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTime)
    .ToListAsync();
```

but i want to use whereif and orderby like

```
var tasks = await _taskRepository
    .GetAll()
    .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input?.Title), x => x.Title.Contains(input.Title))
    .WhereIf(input?.State != null, x => x.State == input.State.Value)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTime)
    .ToListAsync();
```

**Error:**

> 'IOrderedEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IOrderedEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using wrong WhereIf extension, it's easy to miss because you need to add extra using Visual Studio won't offer.

You are using extension which returns IEnumerable

```
Abp.Collections.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.WhereIf<T>()
```

You need to use extension that returns IQueryable

```
Abp.Linq.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.WhereIf<T>()
```

It's an easy fix, just add at the top of the file **using Abp.Linq.Extensions;**

Answer (score 2):

`IOrderedEnumerable<Task>` means that you are working with a `IEnumerable<Task>`.

Entity Framework Core works with `IQueryable<T>` (which represents a database query), not `IEnumerable<T>` (which represents an in-memory collection). As soon as the `IQueryable<T>` is converted to a `IEnumerable<T>`, the query is executed on the database server and the result retrieved.

So: if you are calling a method that returns `IEnumerable<T>`, that method was not made to be used in LINQ to Entities.